# How do I dilate the edges of a mask using opencv?

Tags: opencv

I have a binary mask `cv::Mat`. I would like to dilate the edges of the mask to ensure that I am excluding analysis of regions close to it's masked edges.

My question is, how do I bleed the edges of a binary mask using opencv?

Comment: By "bleed", do you mean [dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate)?

Comment: Correct. Thanks, I will look at the dilate method.

Comment: [Here](http://aishack.in/tutorials/mathematical-morphology-opencv/) is a short tutorial on how to run erosion and dilation with OpenCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "bleeding", I assume you meant the [*dilate*](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) morphological transformation ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology))). This operation will essentially apply a kernel matrix over each pixel of the input matrix. If the kernel is a completely filled 3x3 matrix, it will roughly dilate the edges by one pixel.

```
C++: void dilate(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray kernel, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1), int iterations=1, int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue() )
```

So your solution might go around something like this:

```
Mat input = ... 
Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, 3);
Mat output;
cv::dilate(input, output, kernel);
```

If this example yet does not please you, a better one can be found in the [samples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/morphology2.cpp).